# JavaScript: llamada a método java con AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

Alguien me puede dar una pista de como hacer una llamada a `JAVA` con `AJAX`. Es la primera vez que me toca hacer esto y no tengo ni idea. ¿Alguna ayuda?

EDIT

yo tengo este `tr` que es el importante:

```
<tr>
    <td class="formularioInput" align="left"><expresso:OutputTag
            name="DNI">
            <expresso:ContentTag />&nbsp;</expresso:OutputTag></td>
    <td id = "nombrePersona" class="formularioInput" align="left"><expresso:OutputTag
            name="NOMBRE_PERSONA">
            <expresso:ContentTag />&nbsp;</expresso:OutputTag></td>
    <td class="formularioInput" align="left"><expresso:OutputTag
            name="ROLES">
            <expresso:ContentTag />&nbsp;</expresso:OutputTag></td>

    <td id = "orcidActual" class="formularioInput" align="left"><expresso:OutputTag
            name="ORCIDACTUAL">
            <expresso:ContentTag />&nbsp;</expresso:OutputTag></td>

    <td class="formularioInput">
        <img onclick="lstrImgModifyOnClick()" src= <%=lstrImgModify %> alt="Imagen" />
                    </td>
    <td class="formularioInput" align="center"><indaba:BoxTag
            anchura="90">
        <indaba:TransitionTag name="verHistorico"
            label="jsplVerHistoricoMAY" form="frmDetalle" />
    </indaba:BoxTag></td>
</tr>
```

Con el `onClick` que tiene la `img` sale lo siguiente:

```
<tr id = "newRow" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <td class="formularioInput" colspan="3"></td>

    <td class="formulario_input" colspan="1">
              <input id="nuevoORCID" style="visibility:hidden;" name="NUEVOORCID" type="text" maxlength="16"/>
          </td>
          <td class="formularioInput">
        <img id = "checkNuevoOrcid" style="visibility:hidden;" 
        onclick="lstrImgCheckOnClick()" src= <%=lstrImgCheck %> alt="Imagen" />
        <indaba:TransitionTag name="verHistorico"form="frmDetalle" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="formularioInput">
        <img id = "eliminarNuevoOrcid"  style="visibility:hidden;" 
        onclick="lstrImgDeleteOnClick()" src= <%=lstrImgDelete %> alt="Imagen" />
                    </td>
</tr>
```

Y en el `onClick` de `lstrImgCheckOnClick()` tengo esto:

```
function lstrImgCheckOnClick(){
    document.getElementById("newRow").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("nuevoORCID").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("checkNuevoOrcid").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("eliminarNuevoOrcid").style.visibility = "hidden";

}
```

Esto lo que debería hacer es ocultar todo (que lo hace), lo que no se es como meter un `AJAX` para llamar a un método de java, que me guarde los valores de dos de esos datos en una base de datos. El método lo tengo hecho pero no se como llegar a el.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. [Netbeans tiene un tutorial completo, muy detallado](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart.html). Aparte de eso, hay más información, si haces una búsqueda. Conviene que investigues, que hagas un intento de código y que luego plantees aquí tu pregunta cuando te encuentres ante un problema concreto del programa.

Answer (score 2):

trato de explicarte, al menos cómo funciona todo esto para que te orientes:

> 1. [AJAX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) Es el encargado de comunicar el cliente WEB (tu navegador) con el servidor mediante [JavaScript](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)
> 2. Para ello, el servidor debe levantar lo que se conoce, por ejemplo, como un [servicio REST](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transferencia_de_Estado_Representacional)
> 3. En el caso de Java, hay diferentes modos de crear una API REST, pero [éste manual](https://picodotdev.github.io/blog-bitix/2016/09/ejemplo-de-api-rest-en-java-con-jax-rs-y-spring-boot/)  puede ayudarte. Se utilizan frameworks como SPRING, en los cuales ya están estandarizadas las metodologías.
> 4. Una vez el servicio REST que has creado, reciba la petición desde tu cliente, se encargará de las funciones que le hayas incluido (por ejemplo, el grabar el valor en una base de datos
> 5. En cuanto a cómo hacer la llamada AJAX, te didía que utilices [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Son un conjunto de librerías JavaScript que te ayudarán a [realizar la petición AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Suerte